# Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. Error in Contact.js file

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am trying to get my form populated when I click on the edit pencil button but I keep getting the error 'to many re-renders'. Anyone can help here? down below my two files
I am using firebase to pull out data from a collection and basically I am trying to build a simple application where you can display data from that database and then eventually edit it or delete it

Contact.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ContactForm from "./ContactForm";
import firebaseDb from "../firebase";

const Contacts = () => {
  var [learnerObjects, setLearnerObjects] = useState({});
  var [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    firebaseDb.child("learners").on("value", (snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.val() != null)
        setLearnerObjects({
          ...snapshot.val(),
        });
    });
  }, []);

  const addOrEdit = (obj) => {
    firebaseDb.child("learners").push(obj, (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="display-4 text-center">Contact Register</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-5">
          <ContactForm
            {...setCurrentId({ addOrEdit, currentId, learnerObjects })}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-7">
          <table className="table table-borderless table-stripped">
            <thead className="thead-light">
              <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>email</th>
                <th>score</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {Object.keys(learnerObjects).map(id => {
                return (
                  <tr key={id}>
                    <td>{learnerObjects[id].firstName}</td>
                    <td>{learnerObjects[id].lastName}</td>
                    <td>{learnerObjects[id].email}</td>
                    <td>{learnerObjects[id].score}</td>
                    <td>
                      <a
                        className="btn text-primary"
                        onClick={() => {
                          setCurrentId(id)
                        }}
                      >
                        <i className="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
                      </a>
                      <a className="btn text-danger">
                        <i className="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                );
              })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Contacts;
```

ContactForm.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const ContactForm = (props) => {
  const initialFieldValues = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    score: 0,
  };

  var [values, setValues] = useState(initialFieldValues);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.currentId === '')
      setValues({
        ...initialFieldValues,
      });
    else
      setValues({
        ...props.learnerObjects[props.currentId],
      });
  }, [props.currentId, props.learnerObjects]);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    var { name, value } = e.target;
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.addOrEdit(values);
  };

  return (
    <form autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
      <div className="form-group input-group">
        <div className="input-group-prepend">
          <div className="input-group-text">
            <i className="fas fa-user"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="first name"
          name="firstName"
          value={values.firstName}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-row">
        <div className="form-group input-group col-md-6">
          <div className="input-group-prepend">
            <div className="input-group-text">
              <i className="fas fa-user"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="last name"
            name="lastName"
            value={values.lastName}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group input-group col-md-6">
          <div className="input-group-prepend">
            <div className="input-group-text">
              <i className="fas fa-user"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="email"
            name="email"
            value={values.email}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="form-group">
        <textarea
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="score"
          name="score"
          value={values.score}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          type="submit"
          value="Save"
          className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default ContactForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `{...setCurrentId({ addOrEdit, currentId, learnerObjects })}` on render.

You are updating the useState hook on render, which results in a rerender during which you are again updating the hook resulting in an infinity loop.

You need to update the state somewhere that is not executed on every render.

Comment: Hi Domino987, thanks for prompt response. How would you do it in this case?

Comment: Great. Sorry didn't see your message. If this helped you, could you mark it as accepted so other can find it as well?